# gulp watchers and promises result in crash

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, gulp-watch

I am giving Gulp a try and I set up a task to watch my `.js` files so that when they're modified, my tests are run and my code is linted.

However, and since I started using promises in my code, the watch task breaks. It will run fine the first time I modify a watched file but will crash every time after that with:

```
Message:
    Object.keys called on non-object
Stack:
TypeError: Object.keys called on non-object
    at Function.keys (native)
    at processExports (/Users/hfp/code/coverall/node_modules/nodegit/node_modules/promisify-node/index.js:44:16)
    at module.exports (/Users/hfp/code/coverall/node_modules/nodegit/node_modules/promisify-node/index.js:112:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/hfp/code/coverall/node_modules/nodegit/lib/nodegit.js:96:26)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/hfp/code/coverall/lib/archive.js:10:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/hfp/code/coverall/test/archive_spec.js:6:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
```

Here is my complete Gulpfile, I run the watch task with `gulp dev`:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var mocha = require('gulp-mocha');
var gutil = require('gulp-util');
var eslint = require('gulp-eslint');
var console = require('better-console');
var runSequence = require('run-sequence');
var istanbul = require('gulp-istanbul');
var insert = require('gulp-insert');

var spec_files = 'test/**/*_spec.js';
var integration_files = 'test/**/*_integration.js';
var code_files = ['lib/**/*.js', 'helpers/**/*.js', 'index.js'];
var all_files = code_files.concat(spec_files, integration_files);
var coverage_report_dir = 'test/coverage';
var mocha_reporter = 'list';
var eslint_mocha_header = '/*eslint-env mocha */\n';

gulp.task('mocha', function() {
  return gulp.src(spec_files, { read: false })
    .pipe(mocha({ reporter: mocha_reporter }));
});

gulp.task('cov', function(cb) {
  return gulp.src(code_files)
    .pipe(istanbul({ includeUntested: true }))
    .pipe(istanbul.hookRequire())
    .on('finish', function () {
      gulp.src([spec_files, integration_files])
        .pipe(mocha({ reporter: 'dot' }))
        .on('error', function(err) {
          console.log('Error in tests, not checking coverage.');
          cb(err);
        })
        .pipe(istanbul.writeReports( { reporters: ['html', 'text', 'text-summary'] }))
        .on('end', cb);
    });
});

gulp.task('dev', function() {
  return gulp.watch(all_files, ['test'], { read: false });
});

gulp.task('lint', ['eslint-add-mocha-headers'], function(cb) {
  return gulp.src(all_files)
    .pipe(eslint({ useEslintrc: true }))
    .pipe(eslint.format())
    cb(err);
});

gulp.task('clear-console', function() {
  return console.clear();
});

gulp.task('eslint-add-mocha-headers', function(cb) {
  var truncated_header = eslint_mocha_header.substring(0, eslint_mocha_header.length - 1);
  // turn the header into a regex so if I update the header, this task doesn't break
  var header_regex = new RegExp('^' + truncated_header.replace(/\*/gi, '\\*').replace(/\//gi, '\\/'));

  return gulp.src(spec_files)
    .pipe(insert.transform(function(contents, file) {
      if (contents.match(header_regex)) {
        return contents;
      }
      return eslint_mocha_header + contents;
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('test/'));
});

gulp.task('test', function(cb) {
  return runSequence('clear-console',
              'lint',
              'mocha',
              cb);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had this same issue, but the solution varied depending on various circumstances. One of these 3 usually fixes it for me:

1) Switch to run-sequence's non-callback syntax. For example:

```
gulp.task('test', function(){ 
    return runSequence('clear-console', 'lint', 'mocha'); 
});
```

2) Try defining the eslint-add-mocha-headers 'sequential' dependency right inside runSequence rather than defining required run order in two different ways. This has fixed the issue for me in certain cases in the past. (it's more readable anyway). E.g.:

```
gulp.task('test', function(){ 
    return runSequence('eslint-add-mocha-headers', 'clear-console', 'lint', 'mocha'); 
});
```

3) **This one is your best bet**: try not returning gulp.watch. gulp watch hates being returned: in most cases, I've had this result in repeatedly assigning watchers more to the same files, with the number of watchers going up every time a change is made to a file. This usually crashes the Node process running Gulp (due to memory running out, file lock conflicts, &/or assigning more watchers than the process supports). E.g.:

```
gulp.task('dev', function() {
    gulp.watch(all_files, ['test'], { read: false });
});
```

What line of code is the error being thrown on? Did you get a stacktrace at all?

Comment: Thanks. If I remove the callback, the various tasks step over each other and I don't get the full output while tasks are restarting midway. I can't do without the callback. I removed the return but it makes no difference. The stacktrace points to promisify and the nodegit module. I've added the trace to my question.

Comment: Is it possible for you to use Bluebird (if possible) rather than Promisify? That might solve your problem - Bluebird is a more robust module with fewer gotchas. On another note, did you try outputting the contents of the offending variable directly before the Object.keys call? i.e. console.log(offendingVariableName). Also, what files in the trace above are yours (as opposed to native Node packages or npm modules)?

Comment: I am using Bluebird in my own code but the nodegit module seems to use promisify and not bluebird. Not much I can do here, it's not my module unfortunately. I own `lib/archive.js` and `test/archive_spec.js` only from the files mentioned in the trace.

Comment: Hm...mind posting the code at each of those locations in the stacktrace? 

This looks like an async error, wherein the variable on which Object.keys is run is an object if a callback has returned (or promise resolved or whatever), but is undefined if it has not. Sort of a race condition, wherein the code relies on a section of asynchronously executed code to have finished running.

Comment: (this also makes a ton of sense since it's a very easy error to make when first learning to use promises)

Comment: https://github.com/nodegit/promisify-node/blob/master/index.js#L44

https://github.com/nodegit/promisify-node/blob/master/index.js#L112

/Users/hfp/code/coverall/node_modules/nodegit/lib/nodegit.js:96 `_Cherrypick.cherrypick = promisify(_Cherrypick_cherrypick);`

https://github.com/Coaxial/coverall/blob/master/lib/archive.js#L10

https://github.com/Coaxial/coverall/blob/master/test/archive_spec.js#L6